# Defining a global variable from an ipywidget function using JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I'm using ipywidgets to allow users to choose some value and I want to assign the result of the function inside the widget to a variable outside of the function and use it on the next cell of the Notebook (I tried using a global variable but I couldn't make it work):

```
def issuer_choice():

    from ipywidgets import widgets
    from IPython.display import display, clear_output
    import pandas as pd

    def myfunc(idnum):
        return data.loc[idnum]['cod']

    def on_button_clicked(b):
        global ticker
        ticker = myfunc(w.value)
        with output:
            clear_output()
            print('Ticker CIQ: ' + ticker)

    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', index_col = 1)
    w = widgets.Dropdown(options=list(data.index), description = 'Label:')

    button = widgets.Button(description="Obtain ID")
    output = widgets.Output()

    display(w)        
    display(button, output)
    button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
    return ticker
```

When calling this function as `result = issuer_choice()` and clicking on the button, the code manages to print `ticker` correctly each time, meaning the value inside the function is updated when choosing among the options. However, calling `print(result)` on the next cell prints `None`, meaning `ticker` is not getting assigned to `result`?

*data.csv is just a one column DataFrame where a list of ID's and names are stored.

I'm thinking it has to be about the scope of the `ticker` variable, but I have no clue. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for `global ticker` then make sure `ticker` is already a defined name in your global scope, even if you set it to None, then you can call it later in your global scope.

Also, if you replace things like `read_csv` calls with a simple fake dataframe that gives the same behaviour, it makes it much easier to pick up and work with your example.

```py
ticker = None

def issuer_choice():

    from ipywidgets import widgets
    from IPython.display import display, clear_output
    import pandas as pd

    def myfunc(idnum):
        return data.loc[idnum]['cod']

    def on_button_clicked(b):
        global ticker
        ticker = myfunc(w.value)
        with output:
            clear_output()
            print('Ticker CIQ: ' + str(ticker))

    data = pd.Series({'A':1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3})
    data = data.to_frame(name='cod')
    w = widgets.Dropdown(options=list(data.index), description = 'Label:')

    button = widgets.Button(description="Obtain ID")
    output = widgets.Output()

    display(w)        
    display(button, output)
    button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```